# How to create Erlang Views in CouchDB

Tags: erlang, couchdb, couchdb-2.0

I'm trying to translate my couchdb views to Erlang due to the multiple couchjs process running on my server.

I navigated through some tutorials and some stackoverflow questions but I didn't see anyone talk about the place where I should type the code and press the save button (or the http api). The [old docs](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/EnableErlangViews) talked about temporary views, but it seems that this feature does [not exist in couchdb 2.1](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/issues/932).

I already enabled the [native-erlang-query-server](http://couchdb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config/query-servers.html#native-erlang-query-server)

EDIT:
I tried changing the language and I got this error. Just changing the content-type to `multipart/form-data` did not work either 
[image]

EDIT2: Worked with PUT as Juanjo Rodriguez said

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you have enabled the erlang query server you need to create your design docs setting the language as erlang.

```
{
  "_id": "_design/test-erlang",
  "language": "erlang",
  ...
}
```

[Here](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/query-server/erlang.html) you have the set of operations you can use in the erlang design doc functions.

Comment: Thanks for the anwser. I updated my question. Can you help me?

Comment: Please, try with a PUT